# gdal_translate changes colors converting qgis generated PDF to GTiff

Tags: gdal, qgis-3, pdf

I am producing a geospatial PDF using Qgis 3.10.4. One of my polygon layers is symbolized using red diagonal hatching. The export to pdf gives the correct rendering -

[image]

I then uploaded the pdf to the Avenza Map store, and the colors of the hatching changed to cyan or something close. Wondering whether there might be some CMYK vs RGB thing going on (though that makes no sense since no other colors changed), I tried converting the pdf to GTiff using gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff --config GDAL_PDF_DPI 300 "Llaves NM.pdf" Laves_color_Test.tif
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

So it's not just Avenza's rendering stream that's changing the colors.

To complete the tests, I tried exporting directly to .tif and get this, which is correct:

[image]

I would much prefer to use pdfs, but not if the colors are going to shift.
Is there a setting or something that fixes this issue?